# Android Studio quick documentation always "fetching documentation"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, ide, javadoc

I just moved to Android Studio from Eclipse, and I found that it always shows "fetching documentation" when I use quick documentation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).

How can I solve this problem?
I downloaded the documentation for API 19, and the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue ! Version 0.5.2

Comment: Me too. I have v0.8. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: When the Internet connection is switched off (Wifi off), it runs much more quickly.

Comment: In my case I just didn't download it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51990330/2736039

Comment: Can you set this as the accepted answer? It's the official way to do it and super easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43362107/238753

Comment: This answer here works in 2021 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67087966/8678114

Answer (score 128):

The problem is Android Studio does not automatically update the source link of reference even when the documentation is already downloaded.

The default link in `jdk.table.xml` is http://developer.android.com/reference/ (android studio tries to connect to this online server even if the network is blocked).

To solve the problem, we can just redirect the reference to local source.

## MacOS

On MacOS, the config file `jdk.table.xml` is under 
`~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio<version>/options/`, and the docs are here:
`~/Library/Android/sdk/docs/`, or the custom path of your Android SDK.

In `jdk.table.xml`, find all the lines:

```
<root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/">
```

and modify them to

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/docs/reference/">
```

## Windows

On Windows, the file jdk.table.xml is under 
`C:\Users\Name\.AndroidStudio<version>\config\options`

In AndroidStudio 3.3, modify to

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/docs/reference"  />
```

## Android Studio (any os)

Then, in `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart…` select `Invalidate`, and retry using Quick Documentation. It should display instantly. If it doesn't, select `Invalidate and Restart`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you - this really helped me.

Comment: Worked with AS 2.3 canary 3.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, it worked very well on Android Studio 2.3 on MacOS

Comment: Does anyone have the issue that the http links are added back constantly? Have to do it repeatedly.

Comment: Worked with android studio 3.0 :)

Comment: @Arst I have the same problem... How do we make it permanent?

Comment: @natanavra unfortunately I have not yet found the solution. What I am doing is to manually delete them again and again and restart Android Studio. :(

Comment: htea 1 - Google 0

Comment: @Arst The some problem. I am obligated to correct (copy-paste) the problem constantly.

Comment: Is it actually best to rename all those XML elements? I have followed the above steps and I now have ***24*** sibling rows of `<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/docs/reference" />` in my in **C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\options\jdk.table.xml** file. Wouldn't just one of these rows be enough instead??

Comment: Note: It's essential to replace all the `<javadocPath>` with something like `url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/docs/reference/"` **even if "docs/reference/" does not exist in your Android SDK folder**. It will somehow still work.

Comment: In Linux, you can find it here: `$HOME/.AndroidStudioPreview3.2/config/options` (replacing `.AndroidStudioPreview3.2` with the IDE variant that you are using)

Answer (score 50):

#### Update:

On the newest Android Studio versions you can do as following:

1. Navigate to `Tools > SDK Manager`
2. Select the `SDK Platforms` tab
3. Make sure the `Show Package Details` checkbox, at the bottom right, is checked.
4. Select your target API level from the list, check the `Sources for Android [API_Level]` and click apply.

#### For older Android Studio versions:

Go to: `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`. Select `SDK Tools` tab and:

1. if **Documentation for Android SDK** is unchecked, check it and click **apply**
2. If **Documentation for Android SDK** is checked, uncheck it and click **apply**. After uninstall completes check it again and click **apply**.

Comment: Trying it out... funny thing, I uninstalled the docs, disabled network adapters, and hit Ctrl+Q inside the AS ... got "fetching documentation" of about 0.5s, then the documentation for some Android class popped up. No idea, where it got it from. Now I'm installing the Doc package back, hoping it will fix the fetch times, thank you for idea.

Comment: @Arst you are using probably antivirus SW? Took about 30min on corporate win7 with AV, but under 1min at home with linux. In the end it partially works for me, the fetch times went down a lot, but it still feels like not completely off-line, like there's some tiny ping going on, and the AS is hesitating for 200-600ms before showing the offline version (but part of that time is probably actual fetch, it's from that win7 machine, which is overall sluggish when compared to my main linux machine, looks like the price of running primitive OS). Anyway, this answer should have WARNING. :)

Comment: Finally I see an android documentation that makes sense.

Comment: After A.S. re-install, **Documentation for Android SDK** got unchecked for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: For Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 there's no "Documentation for Android SDK" anymore on the "SDK Tools" tab, but I checked "Sources for Android <SDK level>" on the "SDK Platforms" tab and it worked. That option is only visible when you check the "Show Package Details" checkbox. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 30):

**UPDATE:** out-of-date, please check [@Htea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771262/3193867).

I was having the same issue as you. Here's what fixed it for me:

- Make sure you have the Documentation package downloaded in SDK Manager.
- Exit Studio if it's running.
- Delete the file named "jdk.table.xml" located in ~/.AndroidStudioX.Y/config/options/ (remember to take a backup first!).
- Relaunch Android Studio. should work correctly now and it should regenerate the file automatically.

Note:

- This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 & Android Studio 0.8.11 (**EDIT**: Several users are reporting this solution also works for newer versions of Android Studio).
- If it still doesn't work, try deleting and re-downloading the Documentation package from inside Android SDK Manager then try the above steps.
- If you're running Windows, the file is located at "%UserProfile%.AndroidStudio\config\options", and if you're running OS X, it's located at "~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options" (credits to @Gero and @Alex Lipov).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also works on Windows 7, the file is located at "%UserProfile%\.AndroidStudioBeta\config\options". 
BTW, the Documentation package is under the LATEST Api level group of SDK Manager.

Comment: Works fine, thanks! On Mac, the mentioned file located under ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta/options

Comment: Works for me. Thanks! Just a note: as of Android Studio 1.0, the folder is `.AndroidStudio` (no Beta in the name).

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 16.04 and AS 2.1.2

Comment: Fixed my issue on AS 2.2 Beta 3 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: When using this solution with Android Studio 2.3 it asked me for my SDK's location at next launch. I recommend using Htea's solution instead which really fixes the problem without side effects.

Comment: I recommend Htea's solution below. Doesn't work on studio 2.3.3. Interestingly I had to make changes in both folders:.AndroidStudio2.3 and .AndroidStudioPreview2.0

Comment: Works on _Windows 10_ running _Android Studio 3.0_

Comment: Fixed my issues on Android Studio 3.1.3 @windows7

Answer (score 23):

The reason for me was that I had not downloaded sources for my SDK version defined by [`compileSdkVersion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350902/8583692) property in the build file (now called [`compileSdk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67251145/8583692) in AGP 7.0.0).

So, in Android Studio **4.0** and higher do this:

Go to *Settings*  *Android SDK*  *SDK Platforms* tab  select *Show Package Details* checkbox at the bottom  under your target API Android section check the *Sources for Android xx*  click *Ok* and wait for the download to finish.

[image: The image showing how to do this]

<sub>Thanks to Cyn45 for [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070770/8583692).</sub>

Comment: Thank you! All the other answers here are out of date at this point. Didn't even need to invalidate/restart.

Comment: Thanks! Other answers are outdated indeed.

Comment: Updated for 2022. If anyone is still unable to find in Tools, remember to check "show package details" at the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 12):

As other answers said, it's because the Android Studio is trying to fetch the javadoc online (from `http://developer.android.com/reference/`), which will be very slow if the network not good, especially in China because google is blocked. So we should change this setting and let Android Studio fetch javadoc locally:

1. Download Android SDK Documentation using the `Android SDK Manager`.
2. Open the file ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/jdk.table.xml, see notes below to make sure the correct file is edited.
3. In the file `jdk.table.xml`, replace all `http://developer.android.com/reference/` to the path to your sdk reference folder. For example `file://$USER_HOME$/tools/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/docs/reference` on my Mac.

On OS X, if you have used several versions of Android Studio, there may be several configuration folders for each version (under `~/Library/Preferences/`), you should change the `jdk.table.xml` in the right folder, in my case I should edit `jdk.table.xml` under the folder `AndroidStudio2.2`.

[image: OS X screenshot]

Comment: It's important to use the "sdk/docs/reference/" path even if the sources are stored in "sdk/sources/android-26/" on your computer. It will somehow work.

Answer (score 11):

## On Windows

File location of ***jdk.table.xml***

```
C:\Users\[your windows user name]\.AndroidStudio2.3\config\options\jdk.table.xml
```

**Notes**

- "." before AndroidStudio directory
- version number after ".AndroidStudio". Be sure to edit the version number of Android Studio you're ***currently*** using.  Previous versions will still have directories here as well.

---

### Line to edit

***Before***

```
<root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" />
```

***After***

```
<root type="simple" url="file://C:/Android/sdk/docs/reference" />
```

**Notes**

- `C:/Android/sdk/docs/reference` replace with Android SDK location on ***your*** machine
- if you're copy/pasting location from File Explorer, replace backslashes (`\`) with forward slashes (`/`)
- Each installed Android SDK version will have its own docs XML entry
- Edit the line above in *each* SDK version found in jdk.table.xml (if you want quick docs when targeting those versions in build.gradle). e.g. If you have Android SDK API 25 installed, you'd find a section to edit under `<name value="Android API 25 Platform" />`

## Invalidate Caches / Restart after change!

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Answer (score 5):

I also found this issue with Android studio 0.8.9 & 0.8.14, here's a simple solution:

File -> Invalid Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

---

Sometimes the documentation package may be missing or not up-to-date.

Try open the Android SDK manager(Tool->Android->SDK Manager) and install the 'Documentation for Android SDK' in the latest release, for now it's Android 5.0(API 21), then restart Android studio.

If this happens again, just invalidate the caches.

Answer (score 5):

For android studio 3.4, all you need to do is go to sdk manager -> SDK Tools, check "Documentation for Android SDK" and click apply.

It will automatically update the jdk.table.xml to point to the source you have downloaded.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Simple and works. This answer should has more vote.

Comment: I don't see this option in Android Studio 4.0.  Of course (I think google thinks that change is better than consistency--or even better than functionality).

Comment: This checkbox is not avaliable for me.

Comment: There is "Sources for Android x" checkbox, available for each API, displayed under "SDK Tools" tab when you also check "Show Package Details" checkbox at the bottom right corner. It looks like it downloads the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

1. Close the android studio and delete the c:\Users\xxx.AndroidStudioBeta\ (in my case)
2. Change the android sdk path name
3. Open the android studio, it will ask for the sdk path

Now you can change back the sdk path or using the new sdk path.

You will find Ctrl+Q will work fine. (**Don't import old setting**)

I think we need download the sdk document before set the sdk path to Android studio. But the Android studio should handle this case or give us a option to set it.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick workaround edit `/etc/hosts` (or `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) file and add the line:

`0.0.0.0 developer.android.com`

This will prevent it but you can comment it out when you need to fetch the latest or ones not cached or read the docs online.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: From unknown exactly version, just simply download `Android Documentation` in `SDK Manager` could fix the problem. My `3.4.1` do so.

But I don't know whether older version could works as well or not.

Answer (score -1):

I meet the same issue too,but I solved it just now. I used the Android Studio with SDK before I solved it,and then I download a Android Studio Zip without SDK,and run it,and the issue disappeared.
You can try it.

Answer (score -1):

you can disable it, in Android Studio Preference

Android Studio -> Preference -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Show the documentation pupup in XX ms

[image]

see my another answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317708/android-studio-turn-off-documentation-popup/55194858#55194858)