# Android Studio hangs at fetching documentation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Recently I experienced that Android Studio is hanging a lot. Right in the middle of typing in any editor it will hang and block me from doing anything else for a couple of seconds. Restarting or killing adb wouldn't help.

After a while I realized that this happens if the documentation is being loaded and displayed. This happens mostly for Android documentation, which is quite verbose and also seems to contain images and formatting.

[image: Example documentation that causes Android Studio to hang]

I already tried switching off the `Auto-update from source` option, but that doesn't change anything.

Any ideas what could cause Android Studio to block while it's loading or displaying (or doing whatever with) the documentation?

I'm using **Android Studio 2.1.1**, the latest build with the security fix.

Answer (score 4):

you can check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149069/2133585

> Here's what fixed it for me:
>
> - Make sure you have the Documentation package downloaded in SDK Manager.
> - Exit Studio if it's running.
> - Delete the file named "jdk.table.xml" located in ~/.AndroidStudioX.Y/config/options/ (remember to take a backup
>     first!).
> - Relaunch Android Studio. should work correctly now and it should regenerate the file automatically.
>
> Note:
>
> - This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 & Android Studio 0.8.11 (**EDIT**: Several users are reporting this solution also works for
>     newer versions of Android Studio).
> - If it still doesn't work, try deleting and re-downloading the Documentation package from inside Android SDK Manager then try the
>     above steps.
> - If you're running Windows, the file is located at "%UserProfile%.AndroidStudio\config\options", and if you're running
>     OS X, it's located at "~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options"
>     (credits to @Gero and @Alex Lipov).

**Fix still works for AS 2.2.3 and MacOS 10.12.2 Sierra**