# Get Android Studio to use local javadoc instead of remote

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

Every time I access the Quick Documentation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) for Android classes, I'm always greeted by a 'Fetching Documentation...' text for a few seconds and then I get the actual JavaDoc. Also the response does not seem to be cached, so if I access the same documentation again immediately after, the whole process is repeated.

I've tried the suggestions in this SO post: [Android Studio quick documentation always "fetching documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation#), for example replacing

```
<root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" />
```

in `~/.AndroidStudioX/config/options/jdk.table.xml` with

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/sdk/android-sdk-linux/docs/reference/" />
```

to try to use the local documentation instead of fetching a remote version, however Android Studio seems to reset the value when trying to apply it.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this? I'm behind a corporate proxy that slows everything down as well so this is really starting to bug me.

Using `Android Studio 2.3 Canary 2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update `Android SDK Build-Tools`** through the SDK Manager.

I had exactly your problem and this is what helped in my case.