# How to improve performance of Pycharm documentation fetch

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

When I'm hovering over some Python method in Pycharm, the "quick documentation" window appears instantly, but it will still be fetching documentation for a few seconds before the document appears.

How do I get the documentation to appear **instantly** without the fetch delays?

I have experienced this issue before in Android Studio (which is a modified version of IntelliJ IDEA) and managed to solve it with the help of this thread: [Android Studio quick documentation always "fetching documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation).

Instead of getting Android Studios to fetch the information online each time quick docs appears, the answers suggested downloading all the documentation for Android in a package called the *Android SDK Documentation* and referring IntelliJ IDEA to that package. In Android Studios, this not only works with the core Android methods but also any library that gets imported into your project.

Can I do something similar in Pycharm?

Comment: Alt + q  .... i think

Comment: No, I did not ask for the shortcut. I need to know how I can speed up the process of fetching the documentation so that it appears instantly.

Comment: Did you mean the documentation that appears when the mouse over on a word? or documentation during the code completion?

Comment: I mean on mouse over a word.

Comment: @Simon, Did you solve it?

Comment: No i didn't - it is not the artificial 500ms delay im talking about, it is the network operation to download the docs. I don't want there to be network operations to download the docs, i want them to appear instantly offline.

Answer (score 2):

If you want reduce the delay of the quick documentation, you can go to:

```
Settings->Editor->General
```

In this window, search and enable (if it is not) the option:

```
Show quick documentation on mouse move
```

Now the `Delay` option should be enabled, so you can set the value that you prefer. 
Remember that is in milliseconds.

Let me know.