# Android Studio uses online documentation even when the documentation has been installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I noticed this problem since I did a fresh reinstall of Android Studio. The documentation has been installed in SDK Manager; if my PC is not connected to the internet, when I invoke Ctrl + Q, the documentation shows up immediately but if the PC is connected to the internet, it shows "Fetching Documentation..." and delays (depending on connection speed) to fetch the results.

How do I force Android Studio to use offline documentation always?

Comment: This helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation

Comment: Thanks @FarhadFaghihi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're having the same problem, I applied [the solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771262/6181476)  and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with
 Compiler > Gradle options and enable Offline mode

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix it.