# Android sdk folder doesn't have a folder called "docs" containing the documentation

Tags: android, android-studio

When I hover over something, quick documentation always says "fetching documentation". It takes a few seconds to show the documentation.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation/44142424) question and found that this is because Android Studio is always trying to access docs online and not the offline copy.

This was the answer given.

**In jdk.table.xml, find all the lines:**

```
<root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/">
```

**and modify them to**

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/docs/reference/">
```

However, when I checked, docs folder is missing from that location.

[image]

This is my sdk manager

[image]

This is my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answers are outdated. You can install the docs in the following way:

1. Choose the SDK Tools tab in the SDK Manager
2. "Show package details" must be checked
3. Choose to install "Documentation for Android SDK"

The docs folder will appear

But there are 2 big drawbacks:

the docs are for API 24

folder is 1 GB big

As i remember , it was announced (maybe a year ago), that newer docs will be only available online. Don't know if downloadable packages exist somewhere, or if it's possible to scan and download the entire site at  [Official docs address](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) for offline use.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409366/no-documentation-in-android-studio-4-0-1-linux-mint

Comment: I suspect the release of 4.0.1 hasnt changed the above advice. It seems the docs are now only online