# Hot to fix Android Studio's documentation lookup "Documentation not found"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-14

I cant seem to get flutter based documentation on android studio when i select quick documentation (control Q)

[image]

I have tried reinstalling android studio and have tried re-applying the documentation in the SDK manager.

I expect there to be some documentation of what methods are in the class

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio) Extention

**Install Android Studio**
Android Studio offers a complete, integrated IDE experience for Flutter.

Android Studio, version 3.0 or later
Alternatively, you can also use IntelliJ:

IntelliJ IDEA Community, version 2017.1 or later
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, version 2017.1 or later
Install the Flutter and Dart plugins
To install these:

**Start Android Studio.**

- Open plugin preferences  `(Preferences > Plugins on macOS, File >
  Settings > Plugins on Windows & Linux).`
- Select Browse repositories, select the Flutter plugin and click
  Install.
- Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
- Click Restart when prompted. Ne

Comment: Thank you. I did try that previously. It did not work. I also followed solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378610/android-studio-quick-documentation-always-fetching-documentation  Upon further inspections classes that are within https://developer.android.com/reference/  work fine but new classes from Dart/flutter such as https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html  documentations doesnt show up

Comment: Ok i thought you want that