# What is difference between compileSdk and compileSdkVersion in android studio gradle script when using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I created new android project with jetpack **compose** toolkit with or without kotlin dsl I found that in module level build.gradle file the property compileSdkVersion has been replaced by compileSdk.
I also found that android sdk version "android-S" couldn't be added to compileSdk for that compileSdkVersion = "android-S" needed to be added seperately. My question is what exactly is **difference** between **compileSdk** and **compileSdkVersion**.

> build.gradle.kts(Module:Compose.app)

```
android {
    compileSdk = 30
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion = "android-S"
}
```

Comment: Not sure about it. Now you can use `minSdk`, `targetSdk` and `compileSdk` in your `build.gradle`. It could be related to AGP 7.0.0

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With the new Android Gradle Plugin **`7.0.0`** (currently `7.0.0-alpha14`) you can use:

- [`minSdk`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/BaseFlavor#minSdk:kotlin.Int) instead of `minSdkVersion`
- [`targetSdk`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationBaseFlavor#targetsdk) instead of `targetSdkVersion`
- [`compileSdk`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension#compilesdk) instead of `compileSdkVersion`

These attributes work with an **`Int`** and you can use them with something like:

```
//minSdkVersion 21
//targetSdkVersion 30
minSdk 21
targetSdk 30
```

If you want to use a preview version you have to use:

- [`minSdkPreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/BaseFlavor#minsdkpreview)
- [`targetSdkPreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationBaseFlavor#targetsdkpreview)
- [`compileSdkPreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension#compilesdkpreview)

These attributes work with a **`String`** and setting these values will override previous values of `minSdk`/`targetSdk`/`compileSdk`.

About the String format of the preview versions currently (`7.0.0-alpha14`) it is not clear. Maybe it will change with `7.0.0-beta01` (you can check [this commit](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/5bce01033e4c217c29c55c19631a4d8223fc2a3c:build-system/gradle-api/src/main/java/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension.kt;dlc=671867896f7879aa91dbf1f43b48a1570e677df6)) and it should be:

```
compileSdkPreview = "S"
```

Comment: compileSdkPreview = "S" not supported instead compileSdkPreview = "android-S" i.e. string value need to be android-S

Comment: @VidyeshChuri I've added the related links for all these attributes. About the implementation of the preview String I'am not sure. May be it will change with 1.0.0-beta01: check this commit: https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/5bce01033e4c217c29c55c19631a4d8223fc2a3c:build-system/gradle-api/src/main/java/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension.kt;dlc=671867896f7879aa91dbf1f43b48a1570e677df6

Comment: Do I need to add **compileSdk** along with **compileSdkPreview** to build bundle / release app on playstore?

Comment: @VidyeshChuri In any case you can still use the *old* `compileSdkVersion`. If you are using `compileSdkPreview` it overrides the `compileSdk` value. Are you using 7.0.0-alpha14 ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti is SDK 12 already supported because no matter what I did its either a failed Gradle sync or cannot install the app after changing its compile and target to this new SDK. Here is my question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67649546/12204620