# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

Tags: android, android-12

I was about to update the support SDK to the latest version of Android which is SDK 31 "S" but It has some issue with Gradle sync.

The error

```
Failed to notify build listener.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.   
Could not create task ':app:minifyDebugWithR8'.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
Failed to stop service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService_5d47b2c0-a1a4-43ab-bbdb-bb6abdacb3ba'.
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31
```

This is the setup

```
compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.app
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.9"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Already using the latest AGP `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01`

Already install the Android "S" Preview tools as well.
[image]

Lastly already has the latest AS version preview

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2111.7361063, built on May 14, 2021

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/setup-sdk) not working as well.

```
No signature of method: build_cdzmabn9imuzupf8f433s2vnq.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cdzmabn9imuzupf8f433s2vnq$_run_closure1) values: [build_cdzmabn9imuzupf8f433s2vnq$_run_closure1@6f573027]
```

The Gradle sync is success with

```
compileSdkPreview "android-S"
targetSdkPreview "S"
```

But the app cannot install at all on any device neither release or debug.

What else should we do?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: @HamidShatu not sure haven't tried it again since it looks like it's not ready yet for production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the migration document provided by Google carefully: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/migration

Google usually don't want you to update your `targetSdkVersion` in your production environment before the SDK hits platform stability (see the timeline [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/images/android-12-desktop-timeline-en-may.svg)), but rather test to test it locally. Once the latest APIs are finalized, they expect most apps to update the `targetSdkVersion` to say they certify that this app is compatible with the given SDK level. Lately Google started to enforce a ~year long grace period before they start enforcing that all new apps should target the latest SDK.

Comment: Can you provide the page link of the timeline image?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS it's on this page: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12

with the image address being here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/images/android-12-desktop-timeline-en-may.svg

Comment: Thanks, last question. Does this timeline used on all new SDK version release or only in Android 12?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS it usually changes slightly from release to release, but they are usually communicated clearly every year

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading compileSdk and targetSdk version to 30 from 31 solved my issue.
This is not recommended. But use it in urgent cases.