# compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle: even though I have it defined in my build.gradle file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried adding the openweather api and when I try to sync the `build.gradle` file this error pops up

compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

My File:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I already have CompileSDK defined so idk why this still pops up.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250362/what-is-difference-between-compilesdk-and-compilesdkversion-in-android-studio-gr

Answer (score 3):

This error defines that you haven’t mentioned **compileSdkVersion** and not **compileSdk**. Although both means same but still if you are facing this issue mention `compileSdkVersion` in the build.gradle file.

This issue is relates with the new gradle changes in 7.0.0 so you can use **compileSdkVersion** with string and with int values like below.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion = "S"
//or with same number version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and in my case scrolling further up in the terminal window I saw a message saying that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable was not set.

When I set ANDROID_HOME, my APK release build started working.

I hope this solves it for you.