# When using supabase_flutter, why am I getting compileSdkVersion is not specified error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-flutter

When I attempt to use Supabase flutter in an empty flutter project this happens:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

This nightmare of a build error seemingly appeared around the time I upgraded to Flutter 3.19, but I'm not sure. Tried to fix to no avail.

app/build.gradle looks like so:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.exp"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Comment: `compileSdk` is only used in newer Android Gradle Plugin, so you're most likely using an older version of the plugin, which should use `compileSdkVersion` instead. See the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67251145/13625293)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Thank you very much for the response. The issue still seems to persist even with this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay false alarm. Apparently had nothing to do with supabase. First I performed flutter pub cache repair which revealed a few other issues, first adding a missing line to my gradle defualt configs "manifestPlaceholders += [appAuthRedirectScheme: "com.example.ex"]", then later updating my kotlin version, eventually requiring me to add multidex support to my project. Strangely, it all works now. These issues set upon me quite quickly and I was confused how I got here. The more you know! Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The "compileSdkVersion is not specified" error typically occurs when you haven't specified the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle file. This setting tells the Android build system which version of the Android SDK to use when compiling your app.

To fix this issue, you can specify the compileSdkVersion in your android/app/build.gradle file. Open the file and make sure you have a line like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion <Your SDK Version>
    ...
}
```

Replace  with the appropriate SDK version. For example, if you want to use SDK version 33, your build.gradle would look like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ...
}
```